# Visual Studio 'Format Document' breaks CSS custom properties

Tags: polymer, visual-studio-2017

I am attempting to work with Google Polymer in Visual Studio.  When styling a component, I am using the custom properties as specified by the Polymer API guide as such:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    paper-toolbar {
        --paper-toolbar: {
            border: none;
        };
    }
</style>
```

This generates the following warnings in visual studio:

> Missing a property name before the colon (':') in the "(property) : (value)" declaration.
>
> The block is unclosed, '}' expected.
>
> Missing a selector in the style rule.
>
> Expected a selector for the style rule.
>
> Missing an opening brace ('{') after the selector in the style rule.
>
> Unexpected character sequence.

Furthermore, when attempting to auto-format the document (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D), Visual studio inserts semi-colons that result in invalid css:

```
paper-toolbar {
    --paper-toolbar:;

{
    border: none;
}

;
}
```

(notice the semi-colon after 'paper-toolbar').

I would really like to be able to use auto-format to quickly fix indenting of the html in the same component, however I can't because it inserts stray characters in the CSS.  Is there a way to get VS to understand this CSS, or at least not insert the inappropriate semi-colons?

I am using the VS 2017 RC, however the behavior is the same in VS 2015.

Comment: FYI, the VS Code Insiders build now supports CSS properties and mixins for Polymer. The feature was added via a PR by the Polymer team. They're also working on the `polymer-ide` plugin which integrates with VS Code and Atom, providing code insights for Polymer projects (and other Web Component projects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio CSS editor doesn't expect a block (`{}`) for a property value.  There isn't a way *in CSS* to consume the value you're using legally (it wouldn't be valid in a `var()` for the same reason), but the spec for custom properties does specify that they aren't limited to being consumed by CSS.

Honestly, this is oversight on the implementation of how we handle custom properties.  I've filed a bug to track the issue.  There isn't a workaround to fix the behavior currently, as the formatter aggressively fixes the punctuation as it sees fit.

(Source: I currently work on the CSS editor in VS.)